# An assist ball with some other icons appears while on a call

Tags: android-12, redmi

An assist ball with some other icons appears on phone while on a call. Why does it appear on my Redmi Note11, Android 12 phone?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What apps do you see in Settings > search for "display over other apps"? Do you see any 3rd party app?